# Let $f : (0,2)\cup(4,6) \to R$. Suppose also that $ f'(x)=1$ . Which of the following is ALWAYS true $?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f : (0,2)\cup(4,6) \to R$ be a differentiable function. Suppose also that $ f'(x)=1$ for all $x \in (0,2)\cup(4,6)$. Which of the following is ALWAYS true $?$
>
> a.) $f$ is increasing
>
> b.) $f$ is one-to-one
>
> c.)  $f=x$ for all $x \in (0,2)\cup(4,6)$
>
> d.)  $f(5.5)- f(4.5) = f(1.5)- f(0.5)$
>
> [Source](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf)

Only one option is correct.

My approach: By looking at the options, I can deduce that option-D is correct. As it is given that function is differentiable and $(0.5,1.5,4.5,5.5) \in (0,2)\cup(4,6)$. So it is correct by using Lagrange’s mean value theorem.

But option- A seems to be correct too as $ f'(x)>0$, hence function should be increasing.

Also when we integrate the given differential equation the solution is $$f(x)=x+c$$ and it seems it is injective too.

where am I going wrong?

Comment: You seem to be confusing the scenario where the domain of the function was a continuous interval where a lot of your intuition might have worked with the current scenario where the domain was disconnected.

Comment: @JMoravitz So we can say that as there are two continuous interval for domain, there can be two different value of constant C for different area of domain and this can make other options wrong.

Answer (score 8):

The function $f(x)=x$ if $x \in (0,2)$ and $f(x)=x-4$ if $x \in (4,6)$ is a counterexample for options **A, B, C**.

(Think about $g : x \mapsto 1/x$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ : its derivative is always negative, but the function is not decreasing because $g(-1)<g(1)$)

Comment: Nice explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Your error comes from the fact that the theorems you use for your conclusion are valid if the domain of $f$ is  connected, which it isn't. As the connected subspaces of $ \mathbf R$ are the intervals, your conclusions are correct separately on $(0,2)$ and on $(4,6)$, but not globally.

Comment: Thank you i got your point.